# How can I create a transparent inner border to a circular image?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to create a transparent inner border to a circular image so that it looks like the next image:

[image]

but I have not been able to do it in Chrome using CSS. I know that, in Firefox it can be done with `-moz-outline-radius`, but this is not available in Chrome or in other browsers. Anyone know how to create this border with CSS?

Comment: did you try box-shadow inset?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of this you are looking for?

```css
.bordered {
  background-image: url(https://www.koreaboo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/20633602_495193994153039_1210028231588052992_n-2.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 19px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 19px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 19px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">

</div>
```